# How to name arguments to a UDF?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, user-defined-functions

i'm calling a user-defined function (UDF). i want to be able to name the parameters (like you can with stored procedures) for ease of readability (and to reduce errors), e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM CalculateSettlementSheet(7, 2)
```

would become

```
SELECT * FROM CalculateSettlementSheet(@BankID = 2, @UserID = 7)
```

> When i try it i get the error message:
>
> ```
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
> Must declare the variable '@BankID'.
> ```

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible.

The best you can do is pass in variables.

```
DECLARE @BankID INT
SET @BankID = 2

DECLARE @UserID INT
SET @UserID = 2

SELECT * FROM CalculateSettlementSheet(@BankID, @UserID)
```